# Linq Get 7 days prior to given date

Tags: linq

Is it possible to get all 7 days for a given date using linq query, please?

I could use the other methods to populate the list but thought would be wise to use 2 lines of LINQ if possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hacky but

```
IEnumerable<DateTime> getDays(DateTime date) {

    return Enumerable.Range(0, 7).Select(n => date.AddDays(-1 * n));
}
```

Note: didn't test and not positive about the date methods.